# scraping table with undesirable blank lines in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a beginner in python having trouble when scraping a table. My desired goal is not to have any empty space in the output. My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# I am only interested in some particular blocks from the bitcoin blockchain
url = "https://blockchain.info/block-height/521578"

# Getting table from the url
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'table table-striped')
stat_table = stat_table[0]

for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    for cell in row.find_all("td")[1:]: # look that I am interested only in the 2nd column
        print(cell.text)
```

With the previous code I get the following as result:

```
521578 (Main chain)
0000000000000000002809c9ae7546964580751b506e070f15002b1c1fdd66b3

0000000000000000002d4f2f654945fda08931355e9af871a8c2135a25da9cb6
00000000000000000023583cc0df49783e50c93d807c405524168016c84c0c2a
2018-05-07 06:56:50

2018-05-07 06:56:50
BTC.com

4,022,059,196,164.95

390462291
452
5,440.06056147 BTC
233.87351861 BTC
342.123 KB
0x20000000
ee7c7e2cde5e0f3567c9f635549ec62365e2ac45da517f41cf6c32787c3d8b4d
3688672863
12.5 BTC
0.11100607 BTC
```

But those blank lines are causing me trouble when I want to save a .csv file afterwards. Do you know how to get rid of those blank lines?

If I make a small change in the code I get the data as I want except that not the column I need (I need only the second column):

```
for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    for cell in row.find_all("td")[:1]: # Here is the change
        print(cell.text)
```

Output with the change (look there are no empty lines, but not in the column I need):

```
Height
Hash
Previous Block
Next Blocks
Time
Received Time
Relayed By
Difficulty
Bits
Number Of Transactions
Output Total
Estimated Transaction Volume
Size
Version
Merkle Root
Nonce
Block Reward
Transaction Fees
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take out the `print` statement you have defined within your scraper and try to replace with this `print(cell.get_text(strip=True))`.

Comment: Thanks SIM, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if the value is desired before printing it.

```
for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    for cell in row.find_all("td")[1:]:
        if cell.text != "":
            print(cell.text)
```

Comment: I tried with conditionals but didn't work. The comment mentioned by @SIM did the job, that is, to use:  `print(cell.get_text(strip=True))`